# Processing script error QGIS point in polygon

Tags: qgis-processing

In QGIS version 2.18.2 i get the following whilst trying to execute Vector > Analysis tools > Count point in polygon. Any clues as to how to troubleshoot?

```
Uncaught error while executing algorithm
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
                self.processAlgorithm(progress)
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/PointsInPolygon.py", line 80, in processAlgorithm
                spatialIndex = vector.spatialindex(pointLayer)
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/vector.py", line 211, in spatialindex
                idx = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures(request))
            Exception: unknown
```